# do hCard property elements have to be children or can they be descendants?

Tags: children, microformats, descendant, hcard

Basically I'm wondering if this is still effective as an hcard.

```
<div class="vcard">
<h2>Phone Number: <span class="tel">800-288-3875</span></h2>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hCard properties don't need to be direct descendants, they can be nested several layers deep (as in your example, and many of the examples on the Microformats wiki, e.g. see the [hCard authoring tips page](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard-authoring)).

However, the hCard in your example is incomplete because it lacks some of the [required properties](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard#Property_List), so some parsers might not recognise it.